# how to create a drone secret file?

Tags: drone.io

the docs show how to set a file to a secret envvar http://readme.drone.io/0.5/secrets/

is there a convenient way to do the opposite? e.g. have this ssh key be available in .ssh/id_rsa with all the correct permissions.

And by "convienient" I obviously mean without having to type `mkdir`, `>` or `chmod`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use an ssh key as part of your build, you can add the ssh key to the secret store using the following command:

```
drone secrets add --image=<image> <repo> SSH_KEY @/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Note that the `@` notation is similar to curl. The reason this feature exists is because creating the secret using `cat` (or some other sort of pipe) seems to cause a malformed file to upload.

Once the file is added, you can reference in your Yaml:

```
pipeline:
  image: busybox
  environment:
    - SSH_KEY: ${SSH_KEY}
  commands:
    - mkdir /root/.ssh && echo "$SSH_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && chmod 0600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Note that it is important to cat `SSH_KEY` inside quotes in order to preserve new lines.

You may also need to add the host to `known_hosts` in order to prevent host key issues; change `bitbucket.org` to whatever host you're pulling from in the following, and add it to `commands` (**after** the command shown above, to ensure that the `/root/.ssh` directory exists):

```
ssh-keyscan -H bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

(You'll also need to install openssh-client or equivalent, if it's not already available in your build image.)

> And by "convienient" I obviously mean without having to type mkdir, > or chmod

nope

Comment: yup, that's basically exactly what I was doing. Since you're saying it can't be done any other way, it's good to get confirmation.

Comment: Drone does have an init script (of sorts) that performs environment setup. I will definitely consider looking for `SSH_KEY` and automatically creating the `.ssh` directory and `id_rsa` file in the future.

Comment: ohh, this quotes around the SSH_KEY. Thank you for this answer!

Comment: This does not work for me - getting "Cannot unmarshal 'map[SSH_KEY:<nil>]' of type map[interface {}]interface {} into a string value". My indentation is exactly as your answer

Comment: This answer is outdated. Drone no longer supports string substitution with secrets. Instead you need to declare secrets in the `secrets` block. See http://docs.drone.io/manage-secrets/

Answer (score 1):

In Drone 0.7+ when using Github oAuth2 to authenticate into Drone it automatically adds the Github username and password to the builds `.netrc`.

The password is actually a token [instead of a password](https://github.com/blog/1270-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth). The `.netrc` will look as such:

```
machine github.com
  login <SOME_SECRET>
  password x-oauth-basic
```

This means you can clone private Github repos over HTTPS without having to specify the username/password, i.e. `git clone https://github.com/USER/REPO/git`.

You can also get the same effect locally by adding a `~/.netrc` file and adding something like:

```
machine github.com
  login <GITHUB_USERNAME>
  password <GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN>

machine api.github.com
  login <GITHUB_USERNAME>
  password <GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN>
```

You will have to [generate a personal token](https://github.com/settings/tokens).

For example, if using the Ruby package manger [bundler](http://bundler.io/), you can add the following to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'documas', git: 'https://github.com/Propheris/documas-core.git'
```

The build can do `bundle install` successfully since it will clone the above repo via HTTPS using the Github token. The only issue is that when you do `bundle install` locally it will ask for a username/password. To overcome this add a `~/.netrc` file to your development machine as per the above example.

Answer (score 0):

In drone 0.8+

First, you need to encode base64 if its a binary.

```
base64 -i yourfile.bin -o base64file.bin
```

Then add the secret to drone:

```
drone secret add --repository <repo> --name yourname_keys --value @base64file.bin
```

Once in the pipeline something like this:

```
command:
 - echo "$YOURNAME_KEYS" > some/path/afilebase64
 - base64 -D -i some/path/afilebase64 -o some/path/afilebinary
```