# How do I use the drone secret command in the current version?

Tags: drone.io

I want to add an `ssh` key to my `drone` secrets, but can't get the command to work. I've tried many versions of the command found on various stackoverflow/documentation pages, but none of them work. The command help also gives an entirely different syntax than the one in the documentation...

From [the documentation](http://docs.drone.io/manage-secrets/):

```
drone secret add \
  --repository <registry> \
  --image <image> \
  --name <name> \
  --value <value>
```

This just doesn't work for me.

Then I've found this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330947/how-to-create-a-drone-secret-file) about adding ssh keys to secrets. The answer shows again a different syntax, I tried this way, still doesn't work.

When I try to use the command, I get this:

> Incorrect Usage.
>
> NAME:    drone secret add - adds a secret
>
> USAGE:    drone secret add [command options] [repo] [key] [value]
>
> OPTIONS:    --event [--event option --event option]   inject the secret
>   for these event types    --image [--image option --image
>   option]   inject the secret for these image types    --input                  input
>   secret value from a file    --skip-verify             skip verification for the
>   secret    --conceal                   conceal secret in build logs

Which suggests it should be used like this:

`drone secret add user/repo SSH_KEY <my_id_rsa>`

But that doesn't work either.

So what's the actual way of using this command?

Comment: FYI there is an example in the docs (toward the bottom of the page) that shows how to upload a secret from file. `drone secret add -repository octocat/hello-world -name ssh_key -value @/root/ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is an option to add secrets in the web interface, in the settings page of a repo. I completely missed it and the documentation doesn't mention it.

So no need to use the command line.